# Why is the else statement not working inside a foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, database, loops, pdo

I'm building a script that helps a user reset their password if they forgot it. This specific script firstly checks if the email the user wants the token sent to exists. If it does, the token is inserted into a tokens table.

I am still developing and testing, so I haven't created the mail function yet.

I have an if statement that checks if the email exists, then creates the token. If it doesn't exists, it shows the page to enter an email address again. The if statement is working perfect, but the else is not. I'm pasting the entire file here, though it is only the part with the foreach statement that concerns our problem.

The else statement shows absolutely nothing.

```
<?php
    //generate tokens to verify users who forgot their passwords. Send these tokens to the user's email
    
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/phonebook/config.php";
    
    //get user's email
    $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    //generate token
    $token = $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
    //Convert the binary data into something more readable
    $token = bin2hex($token);
    
    //check if the email entered exists
    $check = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $check->bindParam(":email", $mail);
    $check->execute();
    
    foreach ($check as $confirm) {
        if ($confirm['email'] == $mail) {
            //send tokens to the database
            $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tokens (email, token)
            VALUES(:email, :token)");
            
            $sql->bindParam(":email", $mail);
            $sql->bindParam(":token", $token);
            $sql->execute();
    
            echo "<h2>Enter security code</h2>
            A security code has been sent to the email addres $mail. Enter that code in the box below:
            <form action = 'http://localhost/phonebook/controls/forgotpassword.php' method = 'post'>
            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'email' value = '$mail'>
            <input type = 'text' name = 'token'> <br>
            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Reset password'>
            </form>
            Did not receive code? Go <a href = 'http://localhost/pages/forgotpassword.php'here</a>";
        } else {
            echo "That email does not exist. Please try again.";
            include_once "$paste/phonebook/pages/forgotpassword.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also keep in mind, that if NOTHING WAS FOUND in the database, your `foreach` will never even loop once. So if the mail does not match, nothing is found, so no loop, and therefore no `else`.

Comment: You can't just execute and `foreach` without FETCH'ing anything.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I thought that was a shortcut feature of PDO. Once a statement is executed, you can loop the statement object itself for results. Maybe I'm wrong there (ive never done it that way).

Comment: It's there in the database, that's the problem. I've tested it with an email that exists in my db, and it works. It only doesn't work when I enter an email that doesn't exist. And if the email doesn't exist, it should show the message and file in the else statement. It doesn't do that.

Comment: @IncredibleHat *Hmm.....*, you *could* be right. I usually see things like this where others also mention that FETCH'ing is needed. I'll just let this one ride.

Comment: @towercodes no no, you have a logic flaw here. You are searching the database for the email. If it finds one, then the `foreach` will loop once, and that `if` will always result as `true`, because you are doing the same exact match. However if you search the database for an email that does NOT exist... the `foreach` will NOT loop, and you will never get to that `else`.

Comment: As Emails are unique why do you need a foreach loop to process ONE or NONE results of the query anyway

Comment: I'd like to second/third the notion about ever telling someone `That email does not exist.` Even if you plan on adding recaptcha, it is never a good idea to divulge if an email input is valid or not.

Comment: @IncredibleHat you are right. I think it was my limited understanding of how loops work.

Comment: `for` `foreach` `while` `do .. while` ... they all have their uses and differences and behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotting three problems here.

You compare `$mail` which is encoded using `htmlspecialchars()` against an email address which is probably not encoded.

You fetch several rows instead of one:

```
//check if the email entered exists
$check = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
$check->bindParam(":email", $mail);
$check->execute();

$confirm = $check->fetch()
if (isset($confirm['email']) && $confirm['email'] === $mail) {
    //send tokens to the database
```

You tell the "user" that the email address does exist in your system; this is a privacy and data security concern. Just send something like "If the entered email address is in our system, we just sent a password reset link to it."

Comment: Ye. Using your suggestion of retrieving works. The foreach was the problem.